# How to stop recording with Kazam

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

Using Kazam 1.4.5 on Debian stretch,

How to stop recording with Kazam?

The problem is: the icon on the task-bar does not allows any interaction, so I am looking for some shortcut with the keyboard, however, I could not find any. 
The result is, currently the video is recording for ever until I kill the process.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Obviously, I found the solution 5 minutes after to post the question.

- start recording: <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>
- pause recording: <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>
- finish recording: <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>
- show Kazam: <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>
- quit Kazam: <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>

Note: <kbd>Super</kbd> is usually this "Windows logo" key.

Comment: This should be more obvious. Related issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/kazam/+bug/1833995

Comment: @guettli Yeah, I literally recorded the process of searching for this.

Answer (score 4):

Keyboard are not so full of Super key. Better point out it is generally the "windows" key. Also, such sequences may not work at all under some UI/WM.

Comment: You are right! To me, the fact that all our keyboard have a "Windows" logo on it is a big issue, and that is why I usually intentionally try to fix our vocabulary using a more convenient and generic concept (e.g. G̶o̶o̶g̶l̶e̶ ̶i̶t̶! for "Search for it!") or in this case using "Super" instead of "Windows key".

Comment: I actually scrape the windows logo off of that key.